# Trouble with socket.io in P5.js

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, p5.js

I am making a multiplayer shooter in P5.js and I am having trouble setting up a server using socket.io.

Here is the code for my server:

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('new message', function () {
     socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
        message: 'The message was sent'
     });
  });
});
```

And in my shooter app, I call this in the draw function:

```
if (keyIsDown(32)) {
  gunShot = true;

  socket.emit('new message');
 }
```

then I have a socket.on function at the bottom of my code:

```
socket.on('new message', function () {
   console.log(message);
   console.log("test");
 });
```

However, nothing is being printed out to the console, and I can't tell if the two are communicating or not.

I have linked to all of these in my html file:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>

<script src="libraries/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="libraries/socket.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does the socket.io and p5.js work separately? In other words, can the shooter run without the socket.io?

Comment: Actually got it working, and I feel stupid for missing this before.

I had:

    <!--<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>-->

when really I should have had:

    <script src="//XXX.XXX.X.X:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Where X is the IP address of the host machine